# Sprite is not showing up in pygame

Tags: pygame, game-development

I am currently learning pygame from tutorials. So in the code below, I have followed every step same as shown in the tutorial but still the result differs. My sprite didn't show up. A little help might be useful.

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 720
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0 ,0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Sprite for the player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50)) 
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()                                 #----------------for sound and music
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))   #-----------------setting up screen
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")               #----------------game title
clock = pygame.time.Clock()                         #----------------to check 

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True                                      #--------------variable to control start and stop of game
while(running):                                     #--------------Game loop begins
# Keep loop running at right speed/FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

# Process Input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:               #--------------Check for closing the window
            running = False

# Update
    all_sprites.update()

# Draw/Render
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    screen.fill(BLACK)                          
    pygame.display.flip()                           

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the display, before you draw the sprites in the group:

```py
screen.fill(BLACK)        
all_sprites.draw(screen)                  
pygame.display.flip()
```

`screen.fill(BLACK)` fills the entire `screen` surface with black color. The operation paints over all the surface and all what was drawn before is lost.
`pygame.display.flip()` updates the window by the associated surface. When you do `screen.fill(BLACK)` right before, then the window becomes all black.